# can't display sub array length in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of categories. Categories can have some tasks and I want to count the number of tasks.

```js
const categories = [
    {
        id: 1,
        icon: '⚒️',
        name: 'work',
        color: 'bg-[#F8A94B]',
        tasks: [
            { id: 1, description: 'Do A', completed: true },
            { id: 2, description: 'Do B', completed: false },
            { id: 3, description: 'Do C', completed: false },
            { id: 4, description: 'Do D', completed: true },
            { id: 5, description: 'Do E', completed: false },
            { id: 6, description: 'Do F', completed: true },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'home',
        icon: '',
        color: 'bg-[#B2D198]',
        tasks: [
            { id: 1, description: 'Go to the store', completed: true },
            { id: 2, description: 'Finish X', completed: false },
            { id: 3, description: 'Do Y', completed: false },
            { id: 4, description: 'Clear inbox', completed: true },
            { id: 5, description: 'Make Z', completed: false },
            { id: 6, description: 'Clean room', completed: true },
            { id: 7, description: 'Make A', completed: true },
            { id: 8, description: 'Do dishes', completed: false },
            { id: 9, description: 'Clean WC', completed: true },
            { id: 10, description: 'Go groceries', completed: true },
        ],
    },
]
```

In my template section I have a v-for to list categories and I tried to display the length of tasks with category.tasks.length

```js
        <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
            <router-link
                :to="`${category.name}`"
                class="flex flex-col gap-8 p-2 py-3 capitalize rounded-lg cursor-pointer  h-fit"
                :class="`${category.color}`"
            >
                <div class="flex items-center w-full gap-2">
                    <span class="text-2xl">{{ category.icon }}</span>
                    <span class="font-bold">{{ category.name }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full">
                    <div
                        class="text-lg radial-progress"
                        style="--value: 70; --size: 3em"
                    >
                        70%
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center w-1/2">1 sur {{ category.tasks.length }}</div>
                </div>
            </router-link>
        </div>
```

When I save the code it counts the number of tasks correctly but when the app is reloaded it says :

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: __Categories__ array is defined from the beginning in the _data()_ section or is fetch somehow?

Comment: It's in data for now

Comment: do all category items have a tasks property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code in the snipped and work fine, but as @Laurens points you need to have the correct structure or check if exist or not like I show you in this example:

```js
const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',

            data: {
              categories: [
                  {
                      id: 1,
                      icon: '⚒️',
                      name: 'work',
                      color: 'bg-[#F8A94B]',
                      tasks: [
                          { id: 1, description: 'Do A', completed: true },
                          { id: 2, description: 'Do B', completed: false },
                          { id: 3, description: 'Do C', completed: false },
                          { id: 4, description: 'Do D', completed: true },
                          { id: 5, description: 'Do E', completed: false },
                          { id: 6, description: 'Do F', completed: true },
                      ],
                  },
                  {
                      id: 2,
                      name: 'home',
                      icon: '',
                      color: 'bg-[#B2D198]'
                     
                  },
              ]
            }
          });

    app.$mount('#app');
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
        <div :to="`${category.name}`" class="flex flex-col gap-8 p-2 py-3 capitalize rounded-lg cursor-pointer  h-fit" :class="`${category.color}`">
          <div class="flex items-center w-full gap-2">
            <span class="text-2xl">{{ category.icon }}</span>
            <span class="font-bold">{{ category.name }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full">
            <div class="text-lg radial-progress" style="--value: 70; --size: 3em">
              70%
            </div>
            <div v-if="category.tasks" class="flex justify-center w-1/2">1 sur {{ category.tasks.length }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```